# Sparse random matrix in Matlab with values in different range than [0,1]

Tags: matlab, random, sparse-matrix

How do I create a sparse random matrix in Matlab with a value range different from the default `[0,1]`, say `[-1,1]`? Two things I've tried that obviously didn't work are:

```
p = 2 * sprand(5,5,0.1) - 1
```

which returns

```
>> p = -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000
       -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000  
       -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000
       -1.0000 -1.0000 -0.4850 -1.0000 -1.0000
        0.6814 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000 -1.0000
```

And

```
p = ceil(sprand(5,5,0.1));
p(find(p)) = 2 * rand(5) - 1;
full(p)
```

which returns

```
>> ans =          0  0       0  0  0 
                  0  0       0  0  0
                  0  0       0  0  0
                  0  0  0.3112  0  0
             0.3112  0       0  0  0
```

I would like a solution that doesn't involve any looping and that only uses matrix manipulations or built-in Matlab functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unnecessary to throw away the uniform random variates from `sprand` and allocate a second full matrix of random values. I'd do it like this using [logical indexing](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/matrix-indexing.html?refresh=true#bq7egb6-1) and [`nonzeros`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nonzeros.html):

```
p = sprand(5,5,0.1);
p(p~=0) = 2*nonzeros(p)-1;
```

Alternatively, you can do this (a bit slower for large arrays in some simple testing with R2015a):

```
p = sprand(5,5,0.1);
ne0 = (p~=0);
p(ne0) = 2*p(ne0)-1;
```

It's possible logical indexing isn't supported for sparse arrays in very old versions of Matlab. In that case, you can use [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
p = sprand(5,5,0.1);
p(find(p)) = 2*nonzeros(p)-1;
```

Lastly, you could also implement your own function to do this using [`randperm`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randperm.html), [`ind2sub`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html), [`rand`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html) and [`sparse`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html):

```
function R = sprand11(m,n,density)
%SPRAND11  Sparse random matrix distributed on the interval (-1,1)
idx = randperm(m*n,round(density*m*n));     % Find random indices
[i,j] = ind2sub([m n],idx);                 % Convert linear indices subscripts
R = sparse(i,j,2*rand(1,numel(idx))-1,m,n); % Create sparse random matrix
```

I'm not sure if this is precisely how `sprand` is implemented under the hood, but it should be close. It's also about twice as fast as the above solutions.

All of these options avoid generating a full M-by-N matrix or converting `p` to full and then back to sparse. If you don't mind temporarily creating a large full matrix, the fasted method (assuming you have sufficient memory) may be something like this:

```
function R = sprand11(m,n,density)
idx = randperm(m*n,round(density*m*n)); % Find random indices
R = zeros(m,n);
R(idx) = 2*rand(1,numel(idx))-1;        % Create random matrix
R = sparse(R);                          % Convert to sparse
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually I figured out a way to do it:

```
>> p = sprand(5,5,0.1)
>> d = 2 * rand(5) - 1
>> p(find(p)) = d(find(p))
```

This uses `sprand` to generate the sparse structure, `rand` with [the canonical way](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/floating-point-numbers-within-specific-range.html) of shifting the range of the random values to get a 5x5 matrix with values in the range [-1,1], and then the `find` function to find the linear indices of the sparse matrix with non-zero values and use those indices to assign the corresponding values from the random matrix.

The only downside I see is that you still have to generate the full random matrix, so I would still like to know how to do it more efficiently.